# How to load csv files in my table without using copy?

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, loader

I wanna know if is there any sqlldr for postgre ? I want to have my sql script apart from my loader. ( that's what my boss wants :p)

I created my table, now i need to load my csv file in it.

i already checked : 
pg loader emulates oracles sql loader:

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader/

But i have no idea to use it on windows, and i don't have a compilator.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Good luck with that. Alternatively, you could import the CSV file via a plperlu function using the Text::CSV package, outputing the results as a set of record.

Comment: Thank you, it's working :p !!

Comment: You may want to create an answer with the steps you followed to solve your problem, so it can help others in a similar situation.